# Handshake error in client (OS Error: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242))

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

i have an app published on Play Store. It has been working fine since now and yesterday when i entered my app i have realised that my Cloud Storage from Firebase wasn't working. I have entered the app and it was blank where the pictures were supposed to be seen. Then i debugged the app and i'm getting this error: 
-My app is coded by Flutter/Dart 
-I'm working with Firebase

'''
Handshake error in client (OS Error: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(tls_record.cc:242))
'''

I have checked everything and it's not working. I'm pretty sure it isn't about my codes because it was working yesterday.

Can it be about Firebase Storage rules? Because i have the same rules as i have yesterday and it was working until today.

Need help!

Edit: When i connect another wifi, it works fine.

Edit 2: Somehow the problem went away. I guess it was a problem with Firebase Storage but on their side.

Comment: Could you share more details about your issue or your configuration? Is there any change or any setting in your code that might produce it to work in another Wi-fi connection as you state?